# How to translate this this instructions in a query expression in Django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a set of instructions to query my database and I wonder myself if these are possible in a compact way as Query expression, so I have a model who has a field called `solapin` as you can see here:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ...
    solapin = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    def __str__(self):  # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.solapin
```

and I want to change the `solapin` field for every Question object whose `solapin` has between 0 to 9 characters, adding as '0' characters as the difference between 10 and the current `solapin` length of the everyone as you can see here:

```
from appname.models import Question

resultset = Question.objects.filter(solapin__iregex=r'^.{0,9}$')

for item in resultset: 
    diff = 10 - len(item.solapin)
    item.solapin = "0"*diff + item.solapin 
    item.save()
```

This works perfectly for me, but I want to see if is possible to improve it.

Comment: You may need to help us out by reformatting your code as there seems to be problems with indenting and it would be better if there were no semi-colons at the end of lines.

Comment: @quamrana : sorry semi colon was there because I had all the instructions in the same line

Comment: OK, I think I can see what you are doing. First question is: Does the line `item.solapin =  ...` assign a new string to `solapin` and does it matter that it is not a `CharField` anymore?

Comment: @quamrana : to the `item.solapin` is assigned a string, as you can see  this operation `"0"*diff + item.solapin` become in a string at the end for ex:
one of the current `solapin` I have in my database is `456` so it match with my my query and the variable `diff` for this one is `7` so `"0"*7` is equal to `"0000000"` so to `item.solapin` at the end is `"0000000456"`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with single query using postgres repeat function with django [Func](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/expressions/#func-expressions) and using [Length](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/database-functions/#length) and [Concat](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/database-functions/#concat) functions:

```
from django.db.models import Func, Value, CharField, F
from django.db.models.functions import Length, Concat


Question.objects.annotate(len=Length('solapin')).filter(len__lt=10). \
annotate(
    zeroes=Func(
           Value('0', output_field=CharField()), 10 - F('len'),  
           function='repeat', output_field=CharField()
    ), 
    new_solapin=Concat(F('zeroes'),'solapin')
).update(solapin=F('new_solapin'))
```

Comment: I appreciate your fast answer but I'm trying your first part of the query and it did not work `Question.objects.filter(solapin__in=solapins)` because this just find the `solapin` who match with this list `['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']` and I need all `Question` objects whose solapin has between 0 to 9 characters, and I have Question objects who has solapin like this `456`, `78964` and the return of your query is empty.

Comment: Then instead of `filter(solapin__in=solapins)` use the same filter that worked for you in your less efficient version: `filter(solapin__iregex=r'^.{0,9}$')`

Comment: Hi @DimaKudosh sorry for my delayed answer so I executed you script and it output this error:
`django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such function: repeat`
I dont know if in django there are any function named like this `repeat`
Are there any?
Im using django 1.8.

Comment: What database you use?